# Double Submission with single click

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form that is submitting twice to a PHP CLI script with a single submit click on some rare occasions.  This happens randomly and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
exec("/usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/bcst/db/sender.php $ref $etyp $sid | at now 2>&1 | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d' ' > /tmp/{$ref}.job", $output, $return );
```

I have used jQuery to disable the submit button on click.  But that does not seem to prevent the double submission.

So I have created a unique MD5 hash from the context of the submission and stored into a DB

```
 md5($subject.$message);
```

Now I check for the value in the DB before submitting to the script.  To prevent the double submission.

I have 2 questions.

1. Is there a reason for the random double submission?
2. Is there a better way to prevent a double submission if #1 cannot be solved?

The original form is being submitted using ajax. using the code below

```
                $("#form1").submit(function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                $('#send').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#save').prop('disabled', true);
                $.ajax({

                    url: '/db/process.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#echo').html(result);
                    }

                });
                timer = window.setInterval(refreshProgress, 1000); // function for progress!
            });
```

Comment: jquery:- `$('button class or id').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();..other code});` but it doen't seems that you are submitting form through jquery? Is it?

Comment: Are you submitting the form using jquery ?

Comment: I am submitting using ajax.. sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: serverside: sessions/token

Comment: It's likely that the submission is the problem. Show the code where you actually have the submit click event. It's very unlikely to be "random" as you suggest. Computers are, inherently, not random.

Comment: I have added the jquery ajax submit.

Comment: ok thanks. that looks ok on the face of it, assuming there's nothing else on the page interfering with it. What about the PHP in "process.php" - presumably this triggers the CLI script. If you show that, there might be some logical error in there.